# Sum variable number of columns with multiple criteria on multiple columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula

Looking for some help on creating a formula (ideally Google Sheets compatible) that will allow me to define criteria range for multiple columns and define how many columns to sum.

For example, in the screenshot provided, I am interested in:

- Names A, B, and C
- Program X and Z
- Sum of the first two months (Jan and Feb)
- I would expect the result to give 1050, and if I change the Months criteria to 3, it would add in March as well and total to 550

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOtLn.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C2:F10, COLUMN(C1:F1)-COLUMN(C1)<C12), 
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A10, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A12:A15)), 
 REGEXMATCH(B2:B10, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B12:B15))))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this not work if the values in column B are numbers?

Comment: @kvp1192 no. you will need to use: `=SUM(FILTER(FILTER(C2:F10, COLUMN(C1:F1)-COLUMN(C1)<C12), 
 REGEXMATCH(A2:A10&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A12:A15)), 
 REGEXMATCH(B2:B10&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B12:B15))))`

Answer (score 1):

`=SUM(FILTER(INDEX(C2:F5,SEQUENCE(ROWS(C2:F5)),SEQUENCE(1,C12)),(COUNTIF(A12:A14,A2:A5))*(COUNTIF(B12:B13,B2:B5))))`

Requires Office Excel 365.
The filter is set over the number of columns as mentioned in `C12` and it filters the rows that meet the `COUNTIF` conditions.

If you have an older version of Excel I could workaround the `SEQUENCE` part using double `INDEX`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I get the following Error:

#N/A
FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. column count: 1. Actual row count: 4, column count: 1.

Comment: It was tagged excel-formula but it changed to Google sheets. Those work differently.

Comment: are you aware of any way to achieve this in Sheets?

Comment: Sorry, not my cup of tea.

Comment: Thank you anyway!